# Deprecated documentation about component diagram?

Tags: uml-designer

Martin Corino asks:

I've just installed Obeo UML Designer 7 and was looking at the Component diagram documentation where I found mention of "Required Service" and "Provided Service" tools. However, I cannot find these tools on the Component diagram tool palette. Is the documentation out of sync or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is out of date. I create an issue to remind to update this section: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/884
To create required/provided service, you need to create or add an existing interface to the diagram and then use the usage/interface realization relationship to link the interface to the component.